# need to copy files on client system, is thr any possible way?

Tags: asp.net

I m developin an Online Examination System in C#.net and want to copy files on client machine as soon as exam starts, so that even if internet gets disconnected examinee can continue with test

Comment: You will find you get more answers if you take more time to get spelling correct in your question. Also you may wish to be more specific in your question title, I would suggest "What is the best way To complete a multi-page test, that is resilient to network failure "

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider a client server solution, such as WPF or winforms as this is more suited to this type of development. You can use one click deployment to have this still launched from the web and updated on every run.

If you do decied to use asp.net this will result in a very javascript heavy site with a very slow load in the first page.

To do this you would load all your test qustions into a javascript datastructure on the first page, when every the user when to the next page you would need to, using javascript, collect all the answers and store in javascript. then rereender the entire page using your definitions of the test in javascript with no trip back to the server. then once the test was complete you would need to send your results back to the server, the internet must be active once you've compleated the test.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a download package and provide a link for the user to click to request the files.  You can't force a download.

If your exam in all in one web page, you don't need to do anything.  Once the page appears in the users browser, it has already been "copied locally".

Comment: thnx sir...infact i hav divided my screen in 2 parts in first i m displaying 6 thumbnails and next, previous buttons as soon as any of the thumbnail is clicked the question is displayed in 2nd part. I want 2 store all Questions at the first page call-up on client machine so that if his/her internet connection goes down, he still can have the test. I m coding in C#.net and yes i m using a lot of javascripts code.

Comment: I have managed to code everything else but the only part I am unable to do is that I am unable to copy my files on client machine. If anyone can help or suggest some better way, but I am bound to use C#.net. I am not understanding WPF. can WCF be helpful for this purpose?

Comment: I can't really add anything to what has already been stated.  I think you need to get a basic understanding of HTTP, and what happens when a visitor requests a web page.